# Knockout how add custom column to table during foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hello I need to build in dynamic table with columns(header) from array and rows from other array,
first column in array must be static.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Static</th>
<th>Dynamic 1</th>
<th>Dynamic 2</th>
<th>Dynamic 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Nam1</th>
<th>value</th>
<th>value</th>
<th>value</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have next Knockout HTML model allRoles this is array with dynamic headers

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'tableHeader', foreach: allRoles, as: 'role',afterRender: addFirstColumn } ">                                                  

                </tr>
            </thead>    
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: userRoles,as:'dep'}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <span data-bind="text: dep.name"></span>
                    </td>                   
                    <td data-bind="foreach: {data: dep.roles, as: 'role'}">
                       <span data-bind="text: role.id"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


<script type="text/html" id="tableHeader">
    <th data-bind="text: role.name">

    </th>
</script>
```

how I can add Static ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for the *containerless control flow syntax* of Knockout. It would look something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Static</th>
            <!-- ko foreach: allRoles -->
                <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

See **Note 4** here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your binding to be:

```
<thead>
    <tr>                                                  
        <th>Static</th>
        <!-- ko  template: { name: 'tableHeader', foreach: allRoles, as: 'role',afterRender: addFirstColumn } -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This uses something that knockout describes as a [Virtual Element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) to render your `foreach` binding without the need for a parent node.